Least squares fitting with different linear models
Suppose I have some data $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1,\dots,n$ and I want to fit two different linear models using least squares,
$$
y(x) = \sum_{i=1}^r a_i f_i(x)
$$
and
$$
y(x) = \sum_{j=1}^s b_j g_j(x)
$$
Note that the two basis sets $f_i(x)$ and $g_j(x)$ have different dimensions, $r$ and $s$ respectively. My question is: if I determine one set of coefficients, say $a_i$ with least squares regression, is it possible to determine the coefficients $b_i$ in the other basis without needing to do a separate regression?
If $y$ is the $n$-vector with the $y_i$, we can write (in an approximate least squares sense),
$$
y = F a
$$
where $F_{ij} = f_j(x_i)$. Similarly, we could also write
$$
y = G b
$$
with $G_{ij} = g_j(x_i)$. Therefore we have
$$
F a = G b
$$
Would it then be correct to say,
$$
b = G^{\dagger} F a
$$
where $G^{\dagger}$ is the pseudo-inverse of $G$?
